# What is the correct way to add or update an entity with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to pull data from a rest endpoint and saving it into a database. However I want to update a record if it already exists, or create it when it doesn't exist yet.

I have the following code:

```
private void Sync()
{
        using (var db = new context())
        {
            // get data from rest endpoint
            foreach (var item in array)
            {
                // create entity
                var myEntity = new MyEntity();

                // Method 1
                db.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;

                // Method 2
                db.myEntities.AddOrUpdate(e => new { e.att1, e.att2, }, myEntity);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Which method would work better for the behaviour I want, if at all?

Comment: AddOrUpdate() was intended for Seeding, I don't think it is recommended for this kind of general use.

Comment: How would you know whether the data already exist?

Comment: There's far too much to say about how to update entities to cover in one all-encompassing answer. It depends on specific functional (or even non-functional) requirements. Without knowing the specific requirements this question is too broad and opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to retrieve the existing entity from the DB using its primary key. If it does not exist, create a new entity. Then map the properties to the retrieved/created entity and save it.

```
using (var db = new context()) {
    // get data from rest endpoint
    foreach (var item in array) {
        // try to retrieve existing entity
        var myEntity = db.MyEntity.Find(item.Id);

        // if entity does not already exist -> create new
        if (myEntity == null) {
            myEntity = new MyEntity();
            db.MyEntity.Add(myEntity);
        }

        // map received values
        myEntity.Property1 = item.Property1;
        myEntity.Property2 = item.Property2;
    }

    // EntityState should be set automatically by EF ChangeTracker
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Sidenote regarding API design: most of the time it is better to have explicit create and update methods, because these usecases tend to differ. For example: if some values can only be set when creating the entity (e.g. CreationTimestamp, CreatedBy), but not during update, you got a good handle on this if you split the methods. Else you have to resort to sending additional flags in the command (IsUpdateUsecase).

Comment: Ah I see. I was under the false assumption Enity Framework would handle this for me. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the mvc pattern, you could try

```
 public IActionResult Edit(Myentity updateData)
```

{

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.MyEntity.Update(updateData);
        db.SaveChanges();

        // return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}
```